# swift geoJSON can not encode

Tags: swift, geojson, encodable

I'm trying to get geoJSON:

```
import GeoJSON
import MapKit

let coordArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 77, longitude: 44), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 78, longitude: 45), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 79, longitude: 46)]

let way: GeoJSONLineString = GeoJSONLineString(coordinates: coordArray)

let features: GeoJSONFeatureCollection = GeoJSONFeatureCollection(dictionary: way.dictionaryRepresentation)
let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(features)
```

But  i have error: Instance method 'encode' requires that 'GeoJSONFeatureCollection' conform to 'Encodable'

Comment: It's probably best to ask the authors of the `GeoJSON` library you are using.
Note, there is also some support for GeoJSON in Apple MapKit.

Comment: You need to include the code for GeoJSONFeatureCollection if this is your own type. Remember that for a type to conform to\ Encodable each of its properties needs to conform to Encodable